# Как сделать переадресацию страницы в зависимости от языка браузера?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как сделать переадресацию если язык браузера к примеру французский ?

> ```
> <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://example.com/fr/">
>
>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     var lang = window.navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage
>     if ( lang  != "fr" ) {       
>      LangSelect( lang ); 
>     }
>
>
>
> </script>
> ```

Пробовал так, не помогает, кто знает как правильно вставить код ?

В идеале я вижу это так:

1. Пользователь заходит с браузера с французским языком.
2. Тогда срабатывает.

> ```
> <? php 
>
> if ..(не знаю что сюда написать)...{  include ('../lang/index-fr.php');
>
>  }else{
>
> include ('../lang/index-en.php');
>
> } 
>
> ?>
> ```

**Кто сможет подсказать как реализовать такой код ?**

Comment: сделайте на js переадресацию на этот же url, только с get парметрами: `window.location = window.location + '?lang=ru';` Вместо 'ru' получаете и подставляете нужный вам язык. Далее в php получаете из $_GET значения 'lang' и делаете include нужного вам файла

Comment: для того чтоб не было бесконечного редиректа, перед редиректом проверьте, есть ли уже get параметр в вашем url: `let url = window.location;
if(url.href.indexOf('lang')) < 0 // редиректим`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

Код js:

```
// получаем наш текущий url и проверяем, есть ли в нем get параметр lang.
// если нет, выполняем редирект с добавлением в url нужного нам языка в виде get параметра
let uri = window.location;
let lang = window.navigator.language;
if( uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
    window.location = window.location + '?lang=' + lang;
}
```

На стороне php получаем из $_GET значения lang и подключаем соответствующий языку файл:

```
$lang = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'lang', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
if($lang) include ('../lang/index-' . $lang . '.php');
```

Comment: Так же лучше предусмотреть, что если файла с нужным языком не найдено, то подключать дефолтный файл, например, на английском языке

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, все именно так как я себе и представлял .

Comment: А как дописать дефолтную страницу если язык не найден ?

Comment: Например, так: ` $template = '../lang/index-' . $lang . '.php';
 if(file_exists($template)) {
  include $template;
 } else {
  include('../lang/default.php');
 }`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо большое !